# How to validate field datatypes in json string in .Net Core when all values are in form of string?

Tags: .net, json, .net-core, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to validate the attribute datatypes of a JSON string before deserializing it in .Net Core. The problem is that the values in JSON are in form of string be it bool or int.

Ex: For object:

```
class employee
{

  int id;

  string name;

  bool isActive;
}
```

JSON is:

```
Jobject jObj = JObject.Parse(
{    
   "id" : "12",

   "name" : "john",

   "isActive" : "false"
});
```

I've tried using JSON schema(Newtonsoft.Schema and NJsonSchema) but it compares **type of value in JSON** (ie string here) to the **type of property in the schema**(Schema is generated from the object) instead of comparing **the actual type of value**(like the actual type of "false" is bool). Thus always returns type mismatch error during validation.

Code used for NJsonSchema:

```
schema = schema.FromType<Employee>();

errors = schema.validate(jObj);
```

Is there a better way to do it other than using schema? (Prefered)

Or perhaps add options to schema or so?